# Relation between Heaviside step function to Dirac Delta function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I understand that "delta function" is a distribution, not a function, as in it acts on another integrand, picking out the value of that integrand at a specific point.

The discontinuous function is first defined as  $$\delta_\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases} 0&x<-\epsilon\\ 1/2\epsilon & -\epsilon\le x\le\epsilon\\0 & x\gt-\epsilon\end{cases}$$

Because $$\delta(x) = \delta_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}(x)$$
Therefore in the limit $$\delta(x) = \begin{cases} \infty & x=0 \\ 0 & x\neq0 \end{cases}$$ and that 
$$\int_{-\alpha}^\beta \delta(x)dx=1 \;\; \alpha\gt0, \; \beta\gt 0$$

Given the above conclusions, how can the Heaviside step function $H(x)$ be related to the Dirac Delta Function $\delta(x)$ in the following way?$$H(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\delta(\xi)d\xi$$

Comment: for making $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{|x| < \epsilon/2}{\epsilon} = \delta$ rigorous, you need to define the convergence in the sense of distributions.The definition is that a function sequence $f_n$ is said to converge to $\delta $ in the sense of distributions whenever $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x) \varphi(x) dx = \varphi(0)$ for every Schwartz function $\varphi$ (i.e. $C^\infty$ and decreasing more than polynomially at $\pm \infty$)

Comment: in that framework, the differentiation and integration of distributions is well-defined (it is the main reason why distributions are useful, and it works thanks to the integration by parts)  and yes $H(x) = \int \delta(x) dx$ and $\delta = H'$

Comment: [Here is a nice introductory note](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enIR779IR779&ei=vnz1WrmaF8fpUuaKiZAN&q=When+functions+have+no+value%28s%29%3A+Delta+functions+and+Distributions&oq=When+functions+have+no+value%28s%29%3A+Delta+functions+and+Distributions&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1298621.1305300.0.1305869.18.17.0.0.0.0.353.2470.0j7j2j2.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..7.6.1182...35i39k1j33i160k1j33i21k1.0.5L_haarDlOU) on the theory of distributions which may be useful for the readers of this post. The note provides nice motivations and does not require advanced knowledge of mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the non rigorous definition of $\delta$ stipulates that $\int\limits_a^b\delta(x)\mathrm dx$ is $1$ if $a\lt0\lt b$ (what you recalled in your post) but also that it is $0$ if $a\leqslant b\lt0$ or if $0\lt a\leqslant b$.

Hence $H(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^x\delta(\xi)\mathrm d\xi$ should be $0$ if $x\lt0$ and $1$ if $x\gt0$.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to answer:

1. The distributional derivative of $H(x)$ is $\delta$. So if you want to mimick formally the second fundamental theorem of calculus, that formula is what you get.
2. $\delta(\xi) d \xi$ can also be viewed as a probability measure with support $\{0\}$. The cumulative distribution function is precisely $H$. Your formula is just the definition of cumulative distribution function.