# What is the result of Heaviside function times the Dirac delta function?

Tags: limits, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

As the title suggest, I am looking to understand which is the result of such operation. In fact, I am willing to find the root (numerically) of:

$$
\sqrt{(f(x)H(f(x)))^2+(g(x)H(g(x)))^2}-K=0
$$

The derivative of such thing is:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{H(f(x))^2+H(g(x))^2}}\left[f(x) H(f(x)) \left(\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}H(f(x))+f(x) \delta(x) \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} \right)+ g(x) H(g(x)) \left(\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x}H(g(x))+g(x) \delta(x) \frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x} \right)\right]
$$

Now, the terms like $f^2(x) H(f(x)) \delta(x)$, for $x=0$ are not defined (or at least is what my engineering head tells me, being  infinity times zero undetermined).

On the other side, if I approximate

$$
H(x) \approx \bar{H}(x,\epsilon)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
0 \quad x \le -\epsilon \\
\frac{x + \epsilon}{2 \epsilon} \quad -\epsilon<x<\epsilon \\
1 \quad x \ge \epsilon \\
\end{array}
\right. \quad \text{ and } \quad
\delta(x) \approx \bar{\delta}(x,\epsilon)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
0 \quad x \le -\epsilon \\
\frac{1}{2 \epsilon} \quad -\epsilon<x<\epsilon \\
0 \quad x \ge \epsilon \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Then I have

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \bar{H}(0,\epsilon)\bar{\delta}(0,\epsilon)= \infty
$$

However, this does not convince me at all because, as I saw here [Relation between Heaviside step function to Dirac Delta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479810/relation-between-heaviside-step-function-to-dirac-delta-function) , the Dirac delta makes sense only in a integral sense.

How can I solve this ambiguity?

Comment: The Dirac delta can't be multiplied with something (essentially) discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: Good observation.. but also the Dirac delta is (essentially) discontinuous at $0$... or not?

Comment: The Dirac delta itself is (essentially) discontinuous at $0$, but the problem is that the Heaviside is *also* (essentially) discontinuous at $0$. Thus "in reality" $H(0)$ makes no proper sense (even though we often give it a value anyway). Anyway, when you smear out the Heaviside into something which continuously but rapidly rises, and correspondingly smear out the Dirac delta into something supported on a small interval, you get a result that you can make sense of.

Comment: (Cont.) In technical language, this is *mollification*. But the final result will depend on how you mollify, which is bad for a lot of reasons. Maybe in your engineering application there is some phenomenon that restricts the mollifications you can take, for instance to symmetric mollifiers. This can remove the ambiguity. But in mathematical generality there is no way to remove it.

Comment: I agree with you.. however, if you take the limit to $0^+$, that is I come from the right side of zero, then the Heaviside function is defined and it is 1... that is why I tried to approximate the problem.. By the way, what do you mean by "essentially"?

Comment: "Essentially" means that you can't modify on a set of measure zero to get something continuous at zero. Anyway, if you want to do that particular type of mollification, everything is OK, except that you should know that what you're getting in the limit should itself be some distribution. So you should think about integrating it against a test function. Thus, you should be considering $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \frac{x+\epsilon}{4\epsilon^2} \phi(x) dx$ for test functions $\phi$.

Comment: I think what you get is $\phi(0)/2$, which makes intuitive sense: the distribution that you have should be the distributional derivative of $\int_{-\infty}^x H(x) \delta(x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^x H(x) dH(x)$ which somehow should be $\frac{H(x)^2}{2}=\frac{H(x)}{2}$. That has distributional derivative $\delta/2$, which is what we are seeing. Note that the $1/2$ is exactly because of the symmetry: half of your interval has $H=0$, the other half has $H=1$, so the latter is what is contributing.

Comment: By mollifying with a bias, you will get something other than $1/2$, which is why $H \delta$ does not make strict sense.

Comment: Looking at your original problem, I think you are thinking about it the wrong way. I think you should be proceeding as follows: find all roots of $f$ and $g$. Check whether they are solutions to your equation. (Probably they are not, but you should check to avoid missing it). Say the roots are $r_1<r_2<\dots<r_n$. Now try to solve your equation with no Heaviside functions for $x$ confined to $(r_1,r_2) \cup (r_2,r_3) \cup \dots \cup (r_{n-1},r_n)$.