# How could I prove this property of the Heaviside step function?

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta, change-of-variable

I have been trying to prove that $\partial _x\theta(-x) = -\delta(x)$ from the fact that $\theta(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xdy$ $\delta(y)$, where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function and $\delta (x)$ is the Dirac delta. So far, I have done the following change of variables:

$$\theta(-x)=\int_{-\infty}^{-x}dy\delta(y)=-\int_{\infty}^{x}dt\delta(-t)=\int_{\infty}^{x}dt(-\delta(t))$$

where $t=-y$. Though I think I can conclude my goal from that last equality, I am not comfortable with the lower bound of the integral. I have already checked this post [Relation between Heaviside step function to Dirac Delta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479810/relation-between-heaviside-step-function-to-dirac-delta-function), though it hasn't been truly useful. Any piece of advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\theta(-x) 
= \int_{-\infty}^{-x} \delta(y) \, dy
= \{ y=-z \}
= \int_{\infty}^{x} \delta(-z) \, (-dz)
= -\int_{\infty}^{x} \delta(-z) \, dz
\\= \{ \text{$\delta$ is even} \}
= -\int_{\infty}^{x} \delta(z) \, dz
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\theta(-x)
= \frac{d}{dx} \left( -\int_{\infty}^{x} \delta(z) \, dz \right)
= -\delta(x)
.
$$